# How to fix "unexpected return value" when using lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, return

When I want to use lambda to call a method in another Service.java and then use it as the condition to decide return value. It always said "unexpected return value" in lambda. How can I return it?

```
  public SortOrder transform(SortOrder sort, String  abc) {
    if (sort == null) {
      return SortOrder.A;
    } else if (sort.equals(SortOrder.B) && abc != null) {
      return AnotherService.getString(abc)
          .map(l -> l.ifPresent(m -> {
            if (m.getName().equals("name")) {
              return SortOrder.C; //ERROR: unexpected return value
            }
            return sort; //ERROR: unexpected return value
          }));
    } else {
      return sort;
    }
    return sort;
  }
```

Comment: what is the return type of `AnotherService.getString(abc)`?

Comment: @Naman AnotherService.getString will return a Task<Optional<String>>

Answer (score 1):

The function `Optional.ifPresent` accepts a consumer, which isn't allowed to return a value at all.  The lambda passed to `ifPresent` must have `void` return type.

You're probably best off not using a lambda for that part, and instead writing `if (l.isPresent()) { ... }`.

If you insist on using the functional style, you could write `l -> l.filter(m -> m.getName().equals("name")).map(l -> SortOrder.C).orElse(sort)`.

Comment: I guess the corollary question is how do you get the return the wrapped object?  `if (l.isPresent()) { return l.getObj()? }`

Comment: @end-user Yes, except it's `l.get()`.